# What's the best method to group/ungroup rows in a data table?

Tags: tables, lists, data-tables, grouped-list, child-rows

I've been struggling with a good solution to group/ungroup rows in a data table. We've initially implemented drag-n-drop but that was a nightmare to implement due to 3rd-party library restrictions, & a nightmare to use for end users.

I've come up with a different method that's hopefully more straightforward to use, but I'm still not 100% happy with it. Check out the demo below and let me know how I could improve it.

Some items on my list:

- Make it more obvious what clicking on the checkbox will do. Maybe an edit mode or a tooltip?
- Somehow streamline the ways the "Group Items" buttons are displayed.

One other idea is to mimic how one would group/ungroup elements with a combination of **Shift+Select elements > Right Click > Group/Ungroup** and keyboard commands. However, with this being a browser app that'd also support touch-devices AND is geared toward an older demographic, I'm not sure if that's a good idea.

**YOUTUBE DEMO:** [Grouping & Ungrouping Rows in Data Table Demo](https://youtu.be/bZYx3eqpL7c)

Answer (score -1):

OPINION: If grouping elements is a common action for your user I do not see a problem with your implementation in the demo.

Would the people using this app be considered "power users" would they already be familiar with these actions required? A helpful question to ask yourself is; Would the user require training to know how to complete this grouping task?

What other actions might be assumed by selecting a checkbox? Could it be the case that the user will want to check all the list items and delete them?